# Configuring zlib for compiling and installation

Tags: linux, software-installation, make, libraries

I am trying to install zlib-1.2.8 from within "/root/tmp/zlib-1.2.8/" but I think my configuration options are incomplete.  The configuration command that I'm using is:

```
./configure --prefix=/usr2/lib2 --eprefix=/usr2/lib2
```

Prior to compilation the "/usr2/lib2/" directory is empty so that makes it easy to make comparisons to what is in "/root/tmp/zlib-1.2.8/".  After the

```
make install
```

command is executed, I've noticed that there are a number of *.o, *.lo, *.h, and *.c files in the "/root/tmp/zlib-1.2.8/" directory that are not present in any directory under the target directory "/usr2/lib2/".  This makes me think that my configuration specification is incomplete.  I believe the *.c files would go in an src directory, the *.h files would go in an include directory, I don't know where the *.lo or *.o files would go.  How would I specify these options in the configure command?  I would appreciate it if someone could tell me how to correct this situation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your configuration seems ok to me (you normally only have to override the sensible defaults in `./configure`), you would normally include the build step (`make`). From the `FAQ` file included in the downloaded 1.2.8 archive:

```
13. How can I make a Unix shared library?

    By default a shared (and a static) library is built for Unix.  So:

    make distclean
    ./configure
    make

14. How do I install a shared zlib library on Unix?

    After the above, then:

    make install
```

`make` is the last step of point 13

The resulting directories do not include source files (and should not), but they do include headers (needed for other programs to compile against `zlib`):

```
.
├── include
│   ├── zconf.h
│   └── zlib.h
├── lib
│   ├── libz.a
│   ├── libz.so -> libz.so.1.2.8
│   ├── libz.so.1 -> libz.so.1.2.8
│   ├── libz.so.1.2.8
│   └── pkgconfig
│       └── zlib.pc
└── share
    └── man
        └── man3
            └── zlib.3
```

It is normal that not all results of the `make` step are copied over to the destination during the make `install`